# Migration to databases Domain Users do not have access

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, permissions, security

I migrated databases to new servers, however the applications that were previously used with the databases are failing to load. I have changed the connections and etc. The jobs also seem to be failing. I have a domain account who is the job owner. However, when I try to execute the job under my username I get the following error:

> Executed as user: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM. Login failed for
>   user.....[SQLSTATE 28000) (Error 18456).

Is this related to `Domain Users` not having appropriate read and write access to the database?

How would I give `all domain users` permissions to execute stored procedures.

Comment: Database access is normally granted at the SQL instance level.  If you moved databases from one instance to another, you must ensure that the security principle on the old instance is moved to the new instance too.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that where would I find all this in Management Studio

Comment: On the old server, expand "Security" and then "Logins". This will list all the domain security principals that have been configured with database access on the instance.  Have a look at this question to gain a better understanding of how SQL Server Security works : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973134/understanding-sql-server-2008-security-logins-roles-etc

Comment: In database manager in security of your database remove user and then add it from database manager not your database and give it permision\

Answer (score 1):

Users are tied to logins with SIDS. If you moved your DBs, you may need to recreate that mapping.

You can either create another login for DOMAIN\DOMAIN USERS and go through and manually remap, or
run `sp_revlogins` ([link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246133)) and `sp_change_users_login 'Report'` ([link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174378.aspx))

If `sp_change_users_login 'Report'` finds orphans, run `sp_change_users_login 'Auto_Fix', 'user'`.

Answer (score 0):

on your old server did you also have the SQL server Agent running under NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM? You may need to specify an actual user

Comment: How do I check that in Management Studio. In windows services I can see that its using the local system to run its services.

Comment: you can specify your domain user in the windows services