# Cannot run job NT Authority\System error

Tags: sql-server-2008

Executed as user: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM. Login failed for user
'domainname\servername$'.

I receive this error when I try to run the job. I have full permissions; I have also tried to run this job under sa account. Cannot get this to work. Have been struggling with this for an hour. IS there any fix? Although there is replication, the job runs on the local servers.

Comment: Is this the same issue as your [other question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42812/migration-to-databases-domain-users-do-not-have-access)?

Comment: Yes but the error is different now.

Comment: I think you should edit the other question, and be sure to include all relevant details (i.e., you mention replication (?) here, but not in the other question).